# Regex to allow all php files except one

Tags: regex, .htaccess

I have this regex that allow all php files :

```
^.*\.([Pp][Hh][Pp])
```

how can I exclude a specific file, for example test.php ?

Thanks for your answer,
Best regards

[edit]
I omit to say that it is a reg from a htaccess file, the /i doesn't seems to work, and the ? neither. 
[Edit2]
the purpose is to grant access to authenticated users, except for one file that has to be allowed for everyone.
So I've done :

```
<Files ~ "^.*\.([Pp][Hh][Pp])$">
AuthUserFile /directory/.htpasswd
AuthGroupFile /dev/null
AuthName "Please log in ..."
AuthType Basic
require valid-user
</Files>
```

So, all php files require valid user. 
I would like to add an exception for a specific file, says test.php

Comment: instead of [Pp], you can use a case insensitive p. It will shorten the regex to `/^.*\.(php)/i`

Comment: Is this a mod-rewrite question? Can you post a) what it is that you are trying to achieve and b) your code for what you have tried so far.

Comment: Afair it should be possible to add another <Files> block after this one which allows this file. Not sure though. => <Files ~ "...php"></Files><Files "myphpfile.php">...</Files>

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use a [negative lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html):

```
^(?!test\.php$).*\.([Pp][Hh][Pp])$
```

It might be better to use a case-insensitive regular expression instead of writing things like `[Pp]` for each letter.

```
"/^(?!test\.php$).*\.php$/i"
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, but i omit to say that it is a reg from a htaccess file, the /i doesn't seems to work, and the ? neither. Is there another way to write this ?

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't it be better to implement non-regex check in this case?

UPD:

just add second  directive for the excluded file like this:

```
<Files "test.php">
Satisfy Any
Allow from all
</Files>
```

This will grant test.php to be available for all users.

Comment: maybe, how would you do that ?

Comment: You need to add second <Files> directive like this:
   <Files "test.php">\n
   Satisfy Any\n
   Allow from all\n
   </Files>\n
By this test.php will be available for all.